# Lossy JOIN when using PIVOT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Problem with Oracle 11's PIVOT:  When I execute the following, I get normalized results with data in all fields F2-F4 where data exists; F1 is the key so always has data:

```
select t1.F1, t2.F2, t2.F3, t2.F4
from schema.t1,
     schema.t2 
where 
t1.F1 = t2.F1 (+)
```

Now I go to use Oracle's PIVOT feature to join all the fields F2 - F4 so that there is one F2, etc., field for all F2 fields among as many as 5 rows, all concatenated, as follows:

```
select * from (
 select F1,
 TRIM("1_F2") || TRIM("2_F2") || TRIM("3_F2") || TRIM("4_F2") || TRIM("5_F2") as "F2",
 TRIM("1_F3") || TRIM("2_F3") || TRIM("3_F3") || TRIM("4_F3") || TRIM("5_F3") as "F3",
 TRIM("1_F4") || TRIM("2_F4") || TRIM("3_F4") || TRIM("4_F4") || TRIM("5_F4") as "F4" 
from (
select ROWNUM as RN, T.* from (
select t1.F1, t2.F2, t2.F3, t2.F4
 from schema.t1,
      schema.t2 
where 
t1.F1 = t2.F1 (+)
) T 
) 
PIVOT ( 
MAX(F2) as "F2", 
MAX(F3) as "F3", 
MAX(F4) as "F4" 
FOR RN in (1,2,3,4,5) 
)
)
```

This is returning data such that not all data found among the F2 rows, for example, comes back concatenated into a single F2 row for all records.  For the records where it does work, indeed, I get all data as found in the normalized result.  However when it does not work, no data as found in the normalized result is returned.

Any ideas?  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had the wrong function in use.  The Oracle LISTAGG function does what I need to do.  Example:

```
select F1,
 LISTAGG (F2, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F2",
 LISTAGG (F3, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F3",
 LISTAGG (F4, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F4"
from (
select t1.F1, t2.F2, t2.F3, t2.F4
 from schema.t1,
      schema.t2 
where 
t1.F1 = t2.F1 (+)
) group by F1
```

By popular demand, an example:

```
create table myschema.t1 (
F1 varchar2(10)
)

create table myschema.t2 (
F1 varchar2(10),
F2 varchar2(10),
F3 varchar2(10),
F4 varchar2(10)
)

insert into myschema.t1 (F1) values ('1');
insert into myschema.t1 (F1) values ('1');
insert into myschema.t1 (F1) values ('1');

insert into myschema.t2 (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('1','Hello1','World1','1');
insert into myschema.t2 (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('1','Hello2','World2','2');
insert into myschema.t2 (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('1','Hello3','World3','3');

commit;

select F1,
 LISTAGG (F2, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F2",
 LISTAGG (F3, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F3",
 LISTAGG (F4, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F4"
from (
 select t1.F1, t2.F2, t2.F3, t2.F4
 from myschema.t1,
      myschema.t2 
where 
t1.F1 = t2.F1 (+)
) group by F1
```

You get this:

```
    F1   F2                                                                F3                                                                F4
    --   --------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------------------------------------------------    -----------------
    1    Hello1 Hello1 Hello1 Hello2 Hello2 Hello2 Hello3 Hello3 Hello3    World1 World1 World1 World2 World2 World2 World3 World3 World3    1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Hmmm, redundancies much?  Try running this:

```
select F1,
 LISTAGG (F2, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F2",
 LISTAGG (F3, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F3",
 LISTAGG (F4, ' ') within group (order by F1) as "F4"
from (
select distinct t1.F1, t2.F2, t2.F3, t2.F4
 from myschema.t1,
      myschema.t2 
where 
t1.F1 = t2.F1 (+)
) group by F1
```

You now get:

```
    F1   F2                      F3                     F4
    --   --------------------    --------------------   ----------
    1    Hello1 Hello2 Hello3    World1 World2 World3   1 2 3
```

Comment: This doesn't evaluate either - your brackets don't match.

Comment: @dipdapdop Yes you were right.  And I had the important parts unnecessarily embedded in sub-selects, so I nixed those, too.

Comment: There is still a syntax error in the outer select clause.  Might I also suggest that you provide some test data in a WITH block - it is better to have a fully working example.

Comment: @dipdapdop Yeah, that lousy trailing comma after "F4".  I nixed it.  I'll add some data for the example to.